# Laravel - Where statement and array

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have an array to perform a where statement:

```
$array = ['name' => 'Jhon', 'age' => '27'];
User::where($array);
```

I need to use the same array to perform a search between two different age, I need something like:

```
User::where('age', '>=', '28')->where('age' , '<=', 50);
```

How should I do that using the above array?

Comment: What do you mean by **"I need to use the same array to perform a search between two different age"**? The array you showcased only contains one age. Please clarify what array structure you want for the age range.

Comment: That was just an example, its not actual data.
I want to know how can I search all the records between two ages without use the chain methods but just pass and array to the `where` with the ages range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `whereBetween` method:

```php
User::whereBetween('age', [28, 50]);
```

You can read more about what conditions you can use in the [Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses) documentation.